# preencher input com valor de select em jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando preencher um valor dinamicamente com jquery:

No caso quero colocar o valor do value do plano ao ser selecionado com jquery.

Ex.:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                          <span class="input-group-addon">R$</span>
                          <input id="valor" type="number" min="0" class="form-control payment-value" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)" placeholder="Valor do pagamento">
                        </div> 



<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                          <select class="form-control plan">
                              <option value="39256">Plano R$ 10,00</option>
                              <option value="45659">Plano R$ 11,00</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
```

Em meu JS tenho:

```
this.PLAN_ID = $('.plan').val();
```

e um var data:

```
'plan': parent.PLAN_ID,
```

O problema é que quando mudo o 'plano', o valor não é trocado dinamicamente, ou seja o plano fica com o valor 39256 que é o item default, alguém poderia dar um help?

Obrigadão

Comment: Onde estás a usar `this.PLAN_ID`? E onde queres colocar o valor do `select` quando ele fôr mudado?

Answer (score 1):

Se percebi bem é isto que quer:

```js
$('.plan').on('change', function() {
  var plan = $(this).val();
  $('#valor').val(plan);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                          <span class="input-group-addon">R$</span>
                          <input id="valor" type="number" min="0" class="form-control payment-value" value="39256" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)" placeholder="Valor do pagamento">
                        </div> 



<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                          <select class="form-control plan">
                              <option value="39256">Plano R$ 10,00</option>
                              <option value="45659">Plano R$ 11,00</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
```

Não fiz porque não sei se é isso quer mas caso só haja estas duas hipoteses, e para não se poder mexer no valor diretamente no input `#valor`, pode acrescentar o atributo `disabled` a este `input#valor`